# Provide date job was posted on detail page

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

On the [jobs summary](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) list, the right hand side shows how long ago each job was posted, i.e.,

- 3 hours ago
- 1 day ago
- 2 weeks ago

It would be helpful if the detail page also presented how long ago the job was posted.

For example, if you favorite a few jobs and subsequently take a look at them another day from your favorites list, there is no way to determine how long ago the job was posted without searching for the specific listing and viewing in the summary list.

Comment: Actually, it shows the job's last modification time. Also showing initial posting time would be helpful as well.

Comment: When you mention "the detail page" you mean the _actual_ listing, right? As in, the page displayed if you click on one of the listings on the list?

Comment: Yes. Detail Page == Actual Listing (aka, page displayed if you click the listing link).

Comment: Is there a way by which this has been addressed?